# Is it a general principle that all categories obtained in this way have initial and terminal objects?

Tags: category-theory

Given a pair of functors $F,G : \mathbf{Set} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$, we get a category as follows:

- **Objects.** Sets $S$ together with a function $\hat{S}:FS \rightarrow GS$
- **Arrows.** A morphism $f : S \rightarrow T$ is just a function between the relevant underlying sets, such that $F(f) \circ \hat{S} = \hat{T} \circ G(f)$.

For example:

- if $X$ and $Y$ are sets and we choose $F = X \times -$ and $G = Y$, then we obtain a definition of $Y^X$ as the terminal object in the relevant category.
- if $F = 1+-$ and $G=-$ (i.e. $G$ is the identity), then we obtain a definition of $\mathbb{N}$ as the initial object in the relevant category.

> **Question.** Is it a general principle that all categories obtained in this way have initial and terminal objects?

**Addendum.** As Nex explains, the answer is no: take $F = 1$ and $G=0$, then the above category as no objects. So, I'd be interested in conditions under which initial and terminal objects exist.

Comment: Remark: I guess these could be called "$(F,G)$-bimodules." If I'm not mistaken, a natural transformation $F \rightarrow G$ is the same thing as a section of the forgetful functor from $(F,G)$-bimodules to $\mathbf{Set}$. I'd be interested to learn more, if anyone has a reference.

Comment: Also, and I don't know any higher category theory, but this seems to be some kind of "lax equalizer of $F$ and $G$".

Comment: No. Let $F$ send everything to say a one element set and $G$ send everything to the empty set. Then the above category is empty.

Comment: @Nex, good point! I'd be interested in conditions under which we can conclude the existence of initial and terminal objects.

Comment: Here are a couple: $F$ has a right adjoint $G$ is constant. $F$ is constant $G$ has a a left adjoint.

Comment: This is the [category of $(F, G)$-dialgebras](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dialgebra), and you may find useful references searching for that term.